# Is it possible to import a Collada model that aligns to pixels?

Tags: three.js, collada, sketchup

Assume I have a model that is simply a cube. (It is more complicated than a cube, but for the purposes of this discussion, we will simplify.)

So when I am in Sketchup, the cube is Xmm by Xmm by Xmm, where X is an integer. I then export the a Collada file and subsequently load that into threejs.

Now if I look at the geometry bounding box, the values are floats, not integers.

So now assume I am putting cubes next to each other with a small space in between say 1 pixel. Because screens can't draw half pixels, sometimes I see one pixel and sometimes I see two, which causes a lack of uniformity.

I think I can resolve this satisfactorily if I can somehow get the imported model to have integer dimensions. I have full access to all parts of the model starting with Sketchup, so any point in the process is fair game.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Clarification: My app will have two views. The view that this is concerned with is using an OrthographicCamera that is looking straight down on the pieces, so this is really a 2D view. For purposes of this question, after importing the model, it should look like a grid of squares with uniform spacing in between.

**UPDATE:** I would ask that you please not respond unless you can provide an actual answer. If I need help finding a way to accomplish something, I will post a new question. For this question, I am only interested in knowing if it is possible to align an imported Collada model to full pixels and if so how. At this point, this is mostly to serve my curiosity and increase my knowledge of what is and isn't possible. Thank you community for your kind help.

Comment: Why not make the map view separate from the normal view, draw the map using a 2d canvas context and either append it to the DOM and position it where you like or use it as a texture for a plane/quad. Just render a rectangle for every map block.

Comment: From the top down, they look like cubes, but they aren't really. I actually already have a 2D view, but I wanted to use my Collada models if possible. I could just not have a 2D view, or not worry about it or make a custom model. I was just wondering if what I was suggesting is possible.

Comment: If you want a grid, why not just render them normally without spacing, and then paint a grid over the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been informed by two co-workers that I tracked down that this is indeed impossible using normal means.

Answer (score 0):

Now you have to learn this thing about 3D programming: numbers don't mean anything :)

In the real world `1mm`, `2.13cm` and `100Kg` specify something that can be measured and reproduced. But for a drawing library, those numbers don't mean anything.

In a drawing library, 3D points are always represented with 3 float values.You submit your points to the library, it transforms them in 2D points (they must be viewed on a 2D surface), and finally these 2D points are passed to a *rasterizer* which translates floating point values into integer values (the screen has a resolution of `NxM` pixels, both `N` and `M` being integers) and colors the actual pixels.

Your problem simply is not a problem. A cube of `1mm` really means nothing, because if you are designing an astronomic application, that object will never be seen, but if it's a microscopic one, it will even be way larger than the screen. What matters are the **coordinates** of the point, and the **scale** of the overall application.

Now back to your cubes, don't try to insert `1px` in between two adjacent ones. Your cubes are defined in terms of `mm`, so try to choose the distance in `mm` appropriate to your world, and let the rasterizer do its job and translate them to pixels.

Comment: Clarification: My app will have two views. The view that this is concerned with is using an OrthographicCamera that is looking straight down on the pieces. Also, I'm not putting 1px between objects, that is actually just what it turns out to be. I created a similar version of this using straight up canvas, but wanted to have a 3D option as well. With 3D, I understand that my question is pointless. But with a 2D representation, I feel I should be able be able to see uniform spacing between a grid of cubes.

Comment: Have you tried to share your points among cubes? Can you provide a code sample? A screenshot?

Comment: I don't want to share points. It is intended to be look like an grid of squares (since we are viewing from the top), with even spacing in between. I am not able to share a screenshot as part of this project is under wraps and the code is meaningless. Not sure how either would help anyway, either it's possible or it's not. My guess was that it wouldn't be possible, but thought I'd ask.

Comment: I can't understand your concerns, however it can definitely be done. See the source [of this demo](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/canvas_camera_orthographic.html)

Comment: That demo doesn't import a model via the Collada loader.

Comment: Are you looking for someone willing to do your job? You can create points in code, deserialize from `OBJ`, from `Collada` or read from a websocket. Still are points. The demo shows that with proper geometrics and an `OrthographicCamera`, `three.js` can show a grid. You are too lazy to read my answer, too lazy to understand the demo code, too lazy to adopt it, even too lazy to provide code/screenshots. You are the kind of developer who will never get right answers, will never write proper code, will always come up with a **workaround**. I don't want o waste my time. Good luck with your project

Comment: I never asked anyone to write code. I don't feel the need to share code or screenshots since I'm really just asking a theoretical question anyway: Is it possible? You haven't offered a yes or a no, just alternate ways of doing things and telling me I'm wrong. You've offered **workarounds** which you then bashed. If you don't know the answer, then there is no need to respond.

Comment: You miss fundamental knowledge: the point of using hardware acceleration is that the GPU is fast at doing its things, like **floating point arithmetic** and stream processing. You think that with a 2D context it's different? Haven't you ever heard of canvas transformations? No, maybe you haven't... Do you think Minecraft uses only integer coordinates? Still I don't see gaps. The *theoretic* answer is *you can use your models*. You haven't even recognize your problem yet; you still strive to convert your vertices to ints...

Comment: BTW, do you know what a workaround is? Do you know the meaning of the word? Because I can see no workaround in my answer, there isn't a single line of code, there are no algorithms. I simply encouraged you to do the proper thing: place objects in your world coordinates, and let the environment do its job. If you can't even read plain English, that's not my fault